# The $http_referer behaves like the $document_uri

Tags: nginx

I need set `caller` param in ssi include as a current uri, but $document_uri worked queerly

The part of template with ssi-include:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="ym-wrapper">
      <div class="ym-wbox">
        <!--# set var="panel"
          value="<!--# include virtual='/panel/?project=project_name&color=dark&caller=$http_referer' -->" -->
        <!--# echo var="panel" encoding="none" -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Exactly, `$http_referer`, not `$document_uri`

Nginx log format:

```
log_format  subtimed  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                      '"INC $uri$is_args$args" $status $bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent"
```

Nginx location for /panel/:

```
location /panel/ {
            internal;
            ssi  on;
            proxy_set_header        Host panel.domain.zone;
            proxy_method            GET;
            proxy_pass              http://panel.domain.zone/;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_connect_timeout   1s;
            proxy_send_timeout      2s;
            proxy_read_timeout      2s;
            proxy_intercept_errors  on;
            log_subrequest on;
    }
```

I open the page http://devel.domain.zone and I see in nginx log:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [15/Oct/2015:18:29:31 +0300] "INC /panel/?project=project_name&color=dark&caller=http://devel.domain.zone" 200 0 "http://devel.domain.zone/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"
```

Ok, go to page http://devel.domain.zone/sec/?theme=102
Nginx log:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [15/Oct/2015:18:30:29 +0300] "INC /panel/?project=project_name&color=dark&caller=http://devel.domain.zone/sec/?theme=102" 200 0 "http://devel.domain.zone/sec/?theme=102" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"
```

It turns out that the `$http_referer` behaves like the `$document_uri`...
So, if I set `$document_uri` instead `$http_referer` in ssi include, I see in nginx log something like this:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [15/Oct/2015:18:30:29 +0300] "INC /panel/?project=project_name&color=dark&caller=/ga/ga.js" 200 0 "http://devel.domain.zone/sec/?theme=102" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"
```

WTF?!! At what point is calculated the `$document_uri` variable? How to pass variables into include: as a name or as a value?

Comment: fyi: no idea what you're asking!  what did you do, what did you expect, what have you gotten instead?

Comment: ping.  can you clarify whether my answer is missing anything?  if not, i'd appreciate if it's accepted / promised bounty awarded. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you're asking.  What did you do?  ***What did you expect?***  What have you gotten instead?

According to http://nginx.org/r/%24document_uri, `$document_uri` is the same as just `$uri` (and neither one should not be confused with [`$request_uri`](http://nginx.org/r/$request_uri), which is an entirely different variable).

The [`$uri`](http://nginx.org/r/%24uri) variable, in turn, is also pretty clearly documented (over at http://nginx.org/r/%24uri) — in my own words, it's essentially the state of the nginx `location`/`rewrite` state machine — all the internal `rewrite`s that you perform change this variable, and it is basically always in the process of being rewritten.  Another important point is that, unless you maybe modify this variable yourself, it's also missing the `$is_args$args` part from it, and it's also *normalised*, just as is [`location`](http://nginx.org/r/location) matching, since `location` matching ***is*** actually done exactly against `$uri`.

BTW, for some interesting things that you could do with `$uri` with a bunch of `rewrite` directives, take a look at http://mdoc.su/ (make sure to take a look at its [`nginx.conf`](http://nginx.conf.mdoc.su/mdoc.su.nginx.conf)!) and a simpler but nonetheless noteworthy and useful code sample is also available [on ServerFault: "How do I verify site ownership on Google Webmaster Tools through nginx.conf?"](//serverfault.com/q/477103).

If you are more curious on how these things are implemented in C, you can start your journey at:

- http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_variables.c#ngx_http_core_variables
- http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_variables.c#ngx_http_variable_request
- http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_request.h#ngx_http_request_s
- http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_request.h#uri

Comment: @TobySpeight, is your downvote based on the actual *content* of the answer, or more so on the starting paragraph, "It is not entirely clear what you're asking."?  If my answer is not sufficient, yet the question itself is as good as it's been voted for, how come noone else has any clue whatsoever or even a remote estimate as to an acceptable answer?  Especially after a bounty?  The -2 votes for this answer is completely ridiculous and uncalled for!

Comment: I didn't downvote; I was given this one to review, and the first paragraph looks like it was asking for clarification.  Having read it more thoroughly, it appears that I got it wrong this time, and I withdraw the comment and give you an upvote.  Do please look at your URLs - I think you need to encode `$` as `%24` in a couple of places.